# The Interpretation of Henstock Integral

Tags: definite-integrals

If riemann integral has interpretation as the area under function, then what the interpretation of henstock integral? I always think bout it but don't get it

Answer (score 1):

The Henstock integral is also interpreted as "area under a function".  The difference is that certain functions that are not Riemann integrable are Henstock integrable.  For example, the characteristic function of the rationals on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Can I get the journal bout that statement?

Comment: @Albert Parulian: Better yet, just [look at the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Examples) on the Henstock integral.

Comment: Link `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock–Kurzweil_integral` for Henstock integral.

Comment: Hm okay, but why the characteristic function of the rationals on that interval are not Riemann integrable?

Comment: Not Riemann integrable: all upper sums are 1, all lower sums are 0.